# removing subview from scrollview in swift

Tags: swift

I have removed subviews of a scroll view like this:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)
{
    var scroll : UIScrollView = view.viewWithTag(Tag.Tag_scroll.rawValue) as UIScrollView
    for subview in scroll.subviews
    {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    createScrollView()
}
```

When I rotate the device the first time it will work fine and remove all objects and create new objects. But when I rotate the device the second time, it does not remove all the objects - in fact, the `for` loop isn't entered. Why?

If I am removing subview like,
`for i in 1...20
                {
                    var btnRemove : UIButton = view.viewWithTag(Tag.Tag_imgview.rawValue + i) as UIButton
                    btnRemove.removeFromSuperview()
                }`

from same method..it will work fine..but the scrolling is not working

Comment: The only reason that it wouldn't enter the loop is if the view that you are getting doesn't have any subviews. is it possible that you have more than one view with the same tag? Does `createScrollView` make a new scroll view and not remove the old one maybe?

Comment: createScrollView() will create new scrollview with the no. of buttons. and 1st time all button is removed from scrollview but at 2nd time while scrolling..its not removing..it will append new button at last...

Comment: I think You need to Check createScrollView() function

Comment: and Check your Question  Before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem
I am removing the subview of scrollview and create agian scrollview an subview of the scrollview in createScrollView() method

so the main scrollview , I am not getting, that's why this problem is occurs..:)